# What recordings does there exist of Lester Young playing along with Dizzy Gillespie?

Tags: jazz

Does there exist recordings of Lester Young playing with Dizzy Gillespie, or with Miles Davis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Lester Young / Charlie Parker / Dizzy Gillespie ‎– Early Modern: 1946 Concert Recordings**

Label:
Milestone Records ‎– MSP 9035

Format:
Vinyl, LP, Compilation

Country:
US

Released:
1971

Genre:
Jazz
Style:
Bop, Swing

**Miles Davis With Modern Jazz Quartet, The & Lester Young ‎– European Tour '56 With The Modern Jazz Quartet & Lester Young**

Label:
Definitive Records (2) ‎– DRCD11294

Format:
CD,Compilation

Country:
Europe

Released:
2006

Genre:
Jazz

Answer (score 1):

Jazz at the Philharmonic 1944 - 46. Side 4 with Dizzy. Plus Charlie Parker 2nd track.